# minfied javascript but in gtmetrics says it is not minified

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I have minified javascript through store->advance->developer . 
i also tried it using database query . 
but gtmetrics shows javascript is not verified . what are the possible issues ? 
all commands are done , var/static folder delete , var/cache delete , var/view_preprocessed empty . what is the issue ?

Comment: You need to have mod_deflate enabled in your Apache web server to utilize the compression declared in default Magento 2 .htaccess files.

Comment: once i tried to minify it was done ... but my css was not working so i unminified it again . no only js is not minifying.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166734/magento-2-how-to-do-gzip-compression-and-minify-js-css-files-for-optimization?rq=1

Comment: try this one it have htaccess change

Comment: are you sure we have to do change in .htaccess , i have very bad experience with htaccess file :-p

Comment: :D let's try other wise we will revert it :)

Comment: ok i am giving it a try ..

Comment: already have it my htaccess

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kzdue2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83738/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-samair-ali).